# OutputStreamWriter.flush() delay

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending ascii over a socket like this:

```
    outputStreamWriter(s + (char) 13);
    outputStreamWriter.flush();
```

Everything works fine in my development environment.

Out in the field, there can be a 10 to 30 second delay between flush() and the data being sent over the network (verified using wireshark).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: +1: using a packet sniffer to verify it.

Comment: How are you receiving the data? No buffer there?

Comment: wireshark is the packet sniffer. It was verified. The data is delayed before hitting the wire.

Comment: @andrewmara: That was S.L. Barth's point - well done for verifying it and telling us that you'd done so.

Comment: Oh! Now I see how this site works. Thanks!

Comment: having the same problem. i guess this is related to a bad connection either on the server or the client.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly disable Nagle's algorithm for the socket?

```
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

I wonder whether the socket's `OutputStream` effectively ignores the `flush()` call unless this is set...

Comment: The OS will buffer the data to sent together several bytes in a single packet, so try disabling Nagle's algorithm. Another tip is sending chunks of garbage to force the flush of real data.

Comment: the socket's output stream might not, but that's no guarantee the operating system will not.  The javadoc for OutputStream's flush has a snippet which implies that flush is only guaranteed to the OS level.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that next time we run the system.

Comment: Unfortunately, setTcpNoDelay(true) did not solve the delay problem.

Comment: FYI: The problem turned out to be an unsafe threading issue. I wasn't sharing the Socket among threads correctly.